# Trying to convert an SVG to PNG Image

Tags: javascript, svg, png, html2canvas, canvg

I have been dealing with this for a bit but I can't seem to get it to work. Onclick to resulting png image is empty.  See the code below....

```
function svgToCanvas (targetElem,fileName) { 
    var nodesToRecover = [];
    var nodesToRemove = [];

    var svgElem = targetElem.find('svg');

    console.log(svgElem);

    svgElem.each(function(index, node) {
        var parentNode = node.parentNode;
        var svg = parentNode.innerHTML;

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

        canvg(canvas, svg);

        nodesToRecover.push({
            parent: parentNode,
            child: node
        });

        parentNode.removeChild(node);

        nodesToRemove.push({
            parent: parentNode,
            child: canvas
        });

        parentNode.appendChild(canvas);
    });

    html2canvas(targetElem, {
        allowTaint: true,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {

            var theName = fileName + ".png";
            prev_img = theName;

            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = canvas.toDataURL();
            a.download = theName;
            a.click();

        }

    }); 

}

#Running the function..
var theDiv = $('#divContainingSVG');
var fileNm = "imageName";
svgToCanvas(theDiv, fileNm);
```

Not sure where to go next. I simply need to convert the image to a png and then save it to the server. When testing the download version the resulting png is blank. Note that I'm using... canvg.js (including rgbcolor.js) and html2canvas.svg.js

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it work's in angular/

Answer (score 0):

Actually it turns out that this function works fine.  The issue was a conflict with another function that was included, by mistake, to get the svg.